# I just downloaded MacTeX and TeXmaker and I am trying to quickbuild my first document in TeXmaker but it says cannot find log file?

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I just downloaded MacTeX and TeXmaker and I am trying to quickbuild my first document in TeXmaker but It says cannot find log file?

All of my settings are defaults. I am wondering how I need to setup everything to get MacTeX and TeXmaker to play nice together.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: I can compile when I use texworks or texshop. These came installed with mactex. However I wanted to use Texworks and was wondering why it wasn't working. I suspect I need to edit my paths or something.

Comment: i meant I wanted to use texmaker