# "Log file not found" error with MacTeX and Texmaker

Tags: texmaker, mactex

I have recently installed MacTeX.pkg (http://tug.org/mactex/) as well as Texmaker. 
I have this famous "Log file not found" problem, and I'm still stuck with it even thought I have already checked many other questions that were previously asked.

Comment: related: [I just downloaded MacTeX and TeXmaker and I am trying to quickbuild my first document in TeXmaker but it says cannot find log file?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/94686/579) (closed as too localized)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Do you have the same problem as in the question @barbarabeeton linked, i.e., TeXShop works, but TeXMaker not?

Comment: Does `pdflatex sample2e` from terminal generate a `sample2e.pdf` ? May be you need to configure TeXmaker to the texbin [How to configure Texmaker to work on Mac with MacTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89172/15717). Are you using [latest right version of TeXmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/download.html#macosx) for Mac and save file as `filename.tex` with extension.

Comment: Texmaker is pre-configurated to work with mactex : there is nothing to change to the settings (if mactex is installed correctly, of course). To reset the settings : "Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings". And a new document must be saved with a .tex extension (without spaces or special characters in the name) before being compiled (if the message "log file not found" is displayed, it means that the compilation has failed). As you seem to be french, take a look here : [installation de MacTex2012 et Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/install_mactex.html)

Comment: Thanks user27168. After I reset the settings (Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings) everything works perfectly. But I don't know what changed in my settings.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

([user27168](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27168/user27168)s [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117679/log-file-not-found-error-with-mactex-and-texmaker#comment261379_117679) posted as answer:)

Texmaker is pre-configurated to work with MacTeX: there is nothing to change to the settings (if MacTeX is installed correctly, of course). To reset the settings: "Options" -> "Settings file" -> "reset settings". And a new document must be saved with a `.tex` extension (without spaces or special characters in the name) before being compiled (if the message "log file not found" is displayed, it means that the compilation has failed). As you seem to be French, take a look here: [installation de MacTex2012 et Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/doculatex/install_mactex.html)

Answer (score 0):

The error may be due to a format issue. Try run

> fmtutil --all

to regenerate the format.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Texmaker on mactex...it was being caused by me checking the setting the 'use a "build" subdirectory for output files'. I don't know why this happens, it runs well on a windows version.